Getting rao score from MNLogit in statsmodels
I am doing a multinomial linear regression on a set of matrices which are essentially count tables each belonging to a class. My goal is to identify whether these tables are statistically similar or different.
From my readings so far, given that my frequency tables have a small sample size, I should be using a combination of LRT under chi-square with emphasis on a score test (Rao score).
I understand how to train the MNlogit model by doing this:
model = sm.MNLogit(y, X)
result = model.fit()

My understanding is that llr_pvalue will then give me the p value for my LRT under chi-square. But I'm getting confused by how to get score. I think what I need is the score_test function but I'm unsure what argument to pass. Thanks for your help.
Edit: It seems like the functions used above are not meant to handle count data, alternatives welcomed. Also, bonus point for any solution leveraging a GPU in fitting the regression.
Edit 2: Using this solution we can convert out count table to a table MNLogit can handle.

How are your tables related? LRT and score test only work for nested models. That is one model is a constrained version of the larger model with some restrictions on parameters. They cannot be used to compare unrelated tables. Aside: MNLogit in statsmodels cannot handle data given by frequencies or counts, each observation is a single event with 1 for one choice and 0 for the others. ( https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/8380 )

I think the tables can be considered samples of the same distribution. I'm not sure here what the parameter restriction here would be which is where I need help, perhaps restrict all the parameters? Frequency table might have been a poor word choice, in my matrix I have columns for observation types, and each observation increments the value in its respective column by 1. For example if the columns are (1,2,3) I could say I observed A once, B twice, C three times. So actually perhaps a better phrasing is that is is a count table?

MNLogit, like Logit and Probit are not able to handle observations that are counts. They are designed for the original observation with just on selected choice.

The hypothesis tests on parameters Wald, LR and score test would apply if you can put all tables in one supermodel, and for example test that the parameters are the same across subtables or submodels.

A generalized Cochran-Mantel-Haenszel might work to test that tables are the same but statsmodels only has the standard version for stratified 2x2 tables. Otherwise a log-linear model using Poisson would be another possibility which would be for counts.

Hi @Josef placing all the tables into a supermodel sounds like it would work. If you have a solution to offer as to how one would obtain a Rao score from that I'd gladly accept it.

@Josef could you explain more what you mean by "original observation with just on selected choice" perhaps I can convert my table?

if you have 5 observations with the same choice and same values of explanatory variables, the the count version can have one observation with count 5 at the chosen level of the category. MNLogit requires that we have 5 observations with count 1 at the chosen level.  Additionally, if many observations have the same values of explanatory variables, then we can combine them to counts in each choice, i.e. similar to counts in a contingency table if all explanatory variables are categorical. This count version is currently not available in statsmodels for multinomial models.

So if I've understood you correctly, I would take a row in my table which looks like ("G", 1, 2, 1, "A"), and turn it into [("G", 1, 0, 0, "A"), ("G", 0, 1, 0, "A"), ("G", 0, 1, 0, "A"), ("G", 0, 0, 1, "A")]; where "G" identifies the position observed within a sample "A"; and my regression would be done on the first 4 columns to predict the sample.

Actually, the dependent variable is MNLogit is directly the categorical variable e.g y = ["a", "b", "b", "c"] for the 4 observations your example with explanatory variable values ["G", "A"] for each of the 4 rows (if there are two categorical explanatory variables). The levels a, b, c are internally converted to the dummy encoding, and last level is dropped as reference level.

Got it. You should post an answer which gets the Rae score assuming that table conversion and get the bounty :)

For posterity related question for converting count table to the table described by @Josef https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78584847/convert-count-row-to-one-hot-encoding-efficiently/78584909
