Convert count row to one hot encoding efficiently
I have a table with rows in this format where the integers are a count:
   A  B  C  D  E
0  a  2  0  3  x
1  b  1  2  0  y

I'd like to convert it into a format where each count is a one hot encoded row:
   A  B  C  D  E
0  a  1  0  0  x
1  a  1  0  0  x
2  a  0  0  1  x
3  a  0  0  1  x
4  a  0  0  1  x
5  b  1  0  0  y
6  b  0  1  0  y
7  b  0  1  0  y

I wrote inefficient code which achieves this
# Sample DataFrame
data = {
    'A': ['a', 'b'],
    'B': [2, 1],
    'C': [0, 2],
    'D': [3, 0],
    'E': ['x', 'y']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    first_val = row.iloc[0]
    last_val = row.iloc[-1]
    middle_vals = row.iloc[1:-1].astype(int)
    for i in range(len(middle_vals)):
        new_data = [first_val] + [1 if i == j else 0 for j in range(len(middle_vals))] + [last_val]
        new_rows = pd.DataFrame([new_data] * middle_vals.iloc[i], columns=df.columns)
        new_df = pd.concat([new_df, new_rows], ignore_index=True)

Any tips for vectorizing this operation which is incredibly slow? I realize a concat operation per iteration is a big issue, so I did try a batching solution where I collect chunks of new_rows and then concat. This remains slow.

repeating concat in a loop is always slow as you're growing the DataFrame quadratically

Here is a full numpy solution, I would expect this to be faster than reshaping:
import numpy as np

num_cols = ['B', 'C', 'D']

# convert to numpy array
a = df[num_cols].to_numpy()

# build indices to repeat
idx = np.repeat(np.arange(a.shape[0]), a.sum(1))
# array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1])

# build column indices to repeat
cols = np.repeat(np.tile(np.arange(a.shape[1]), a.shape[0]), a.flat)
# array([0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 1, 1])

# assign 1s
b = np.zeros((len(idx), len(num_cols)), dtype=int)
b[np.arange(len(idx)), cols] = 1

# repeat and update DataFrame
out = df.iloc[idx]
out.loc[:, num_cols] = b

Output:
   A  B  C  D  E
0  a  1  0  0  x
0  a  1  0  0  x
0  a  0  0  1  x
0  a  0  0  1  x
0  a  0  0  1  x
1  b  1  0  0  y
1  b  0  1  0  y
1  b  0  1  0  y

timings
# setup
N = 10_000
df = (pd.DataFrame(np.clip(np.random.randint(-10, 15, (N, 10)), 0, 15)).assign(A=np.arange(N), E=np.arange(N))
      [['A', 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 'E']]
     )

# numpy approach (this one)
45.2 ms ± 6.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

# list approach (@EmiOB)
249 ms ± 36.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# pure pandas melt+repeat+pivot approach
3.68 s ± 146 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

comparison for up to ~2M rows (10 cols of numbers)


Very elegant. np solution looks highly optimized.

can always rely on @mozway to bring the best solutions

Creative solution, thanks! I appreciate the insights into timing. I'm curious if you've benchmarked memory use? I suspect this is remains efficient.

No I haven't, but if you do, please share :) I think the cols = np.repeat(np.tile(np.arange(a.shape[1]), a.shape[0]), a.flat) could be improved by using broadcasting, but a better way didn't pop yet in my mind

@mozway I ran a simple memory profile, wasn't sure how to share it so here's a pastebin link of the output. Re-used your setup with N=10_000. Looks like numpy is indeed most efficient considering peak and increment. https://pastebin.com/mZ3QPhzb

Thanks for sharing! The numpy approach will roughly need up to 5x the space used for the numeric columns in the input, (input, input array a, intermediate to build cols, b, output)

It is always slower to build a dataframe in a for loop like you're doing.  See this answer for more details on why.
If you still want to do it this way, it is quicker to append each new row to a list, and turn that into one big dataframe at the end, like this:
new_df_list = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    first_val = row.iloc[0]
    last_val = row.iloc[-1]
    middle_vals = row.iloc[1:-1].astype(int)
    for i in range(len(middle_vals)):
        new_data = [first_val] + [1 if i == j else 0 for j in range(len(middle_vals))] + [last_val]
        for k in range(middle_vals.iloc[i]):
            new_df_list.append(new_data)

new_df = pd.DataFrame(new_df_list, columns=df.columns)

You can also turn your dataframe into a list of lists, and iterate over that instead of using itterrows, which will be slightly quicker again:
new_df_list = []
for row in df.values.tolist():
    first_val = row[0]
    last_val = row[-1]
    middle_vals = row[1:-1]
    for i in range(len(middle_vals)):
        new_data = [first_val] + [1 if i == j else 0 for j in range(len(middle_vals))] + [last_val]
        for k in range(middle_vals[i]):
            new_df_list.append(new_data)

new_df = pd.DataFrame(new_df_list, columns=df.columns)


I actually tried this as well but iterrows is a big bottleneck still.

you don't actually use the index, so you could just iterate through the rows, but mozway's answer is probably going to be the most efficient

Iterating is ALWAYS a last resource and should be therefore avoided

from my small test, turning the df into lists is faster than Mozway's solution, but that solution does avoid iterating

@EmiOB That's interesting, what happens if you try a larger dataset?

@donkey that was with a larger dataset, I repeated your small df by 1000, as on two rows all methods just showed as taking 0.0 secconds.  I only used time.time() between running them, so not a robust time test, but I got my last method taking 0.1 secconds vs 0.5 on mozway.  Didn't look at memory/cpu usage, which might also be important to consider.

@donkey Mozway's new solution is much faster again though, so I would use that.

I think the list approach might be relatively efficient, I'll run some tests ;)

Right, I think considering memory as well is interesting here, at least for me as I anticipate a frame with over 5 million rows. But I didn't want to immediately burden the question.

I added a detailed comparison, the list approach was actually much better than the pandas reshaping ;)

@mozway yeah, I was surprised at that!

(FWIW I think your approach should also be upvoted)

One option using melt+pivot_table+Index.repeat:
# non-integer columns
cols = ['A', 'E']

# reshape to long
# duplicate rows
# reshape to wide
out = (df.melt(cols)
         .loc[lambda x: x.index.repeat(x['value'])].reset_index()
         .assign(n=lambda x: x.groupby(cols+['index']).cumcount())
         .pivot_table(index=cols+['n', 'index'],
                      columns='variable', values='value',
                      aggfunc=lambda x: 1, fill_value=0)
         .reset_index()
         .sort_values(by=cols+['index'], kind='stable', ignore_index=True)
         .reindex(columns=df.columns, fill_value=0)
)

Output:
   A  B  C  D  E
0  a  1  0  0  x
1  a  1  0  0  x
2  a  0  0  1  x
3  a  0  0  1  x
4  a  0  0  1  x
5  b  1  0  0  y
6  b  0  1  0  y
7  b  0  1  0  y

Intermediates:
# melt
   A  E variable  value
0  a  x        B      2
1  b  y        B      1
2  a  x        C      0
3  b  y        C      2
4  a  x        D      3
5  b  y        D      0

# repeat rows with loc+Index.repeat
# and deduplicate with cumcount (column n)
   index  A  E variable  value  n
0      0  a  x        B      2  0
1      0  a  x        B      2  1
2      1  b  y        B      1  0
3      3  b  y        C      2  0
4      3  b  y        C      2  1
5      4  a  x        D      3  0
6      4  a  x        D      3  1
7      4  a  x        D      3  2

# reshape with pivot
variable     B  C  D
A E n index         
a x 0 0      1  0  0
      4      0  0  1
    1 0      1  0  0
      4      0  0  1
    2 4      0  0  1
b y 0 1      1  0  0
      3      0  1  0
    1 3      0  1  0

# reorder rows
variable  A  E  n  index  B  C  D
0         a  x  0      0  1  0  0
1         a  x  1      0  1  0  0
2         a  x  0      4  0  0  1
3         a  x  1      4  0  0  1
4         a  x  2      4  0  0  1
5         b  y  0      1  1  0  0
6         b  y  0      3  0  1  0
7         b  y  1      3  0  1  0

# cleanup columns
   A  B  C  D  E
0  a  1  0  0  x
1  a  1  0  0  x
2  a  0  0  1  x
3  a  0  0  1  x
4  a  0  0  1  x
5  b  1  0  0  y
6  b  0  1  0  y
7  b  0  1  0  y


Thanks for this answer. Would you mind breaking it down?

Sure, give me a moment, I was writing another approach ;)

I added a breakdown of the steps, but I'd now encourage you to test this alternative which I'd expect to be much faster.

Here is way using np.eye() then using combine_first() after converting to a DataFrame.
cols = ['B','C','D']
e = np.eye(len(cols))
idx = np.repeat(np.arange(len(df)),df[cols].sum(axis=1))
a = np.repeat(np.concatenate([e]*len(df)),np.ravel(df[cols]),axis=0)
df = pd.DataFrame(a,index = idx,columns = cols).combine_first(df)

Output:
   A    B    C    D  E
0  a  1.0  0.0  0.0  x
0  a  1.0  0.0  0.0  x
0  a  0.0  0.0  1.0  x
0  a  0.0  0.0  1.0  x
0  a  0.0  0.0  1.0  x
1  b  1.0  0.0  0.0  y
1  b  0.0  1.0  0.0  y
1  b  0.0  1.0  0.0  y


Modification of Mozway's answer to make it more efficient for Huge and complex datasets.
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix

# Sample DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': ['a', 'b'],
    'B': [2, 1],
    'C': [0, 2],
    'D': [3, 0],
    'E': ['x', 'y']
})

# Define numerical columns
num_cols = ['B', 'C', 'D']

# Convert numerical columns to numpy array
num_values = df[num_cols].to_numpy()

# Build row indices to repeat
row_indices = np.repeat(np.arange(num_values.shape[0]), num_values.sum(axis=1))

# Build column indices to repeat
cols = np.repeat(np.tile(np.arange(num_values.shape[1]), num_values.shape[0]), num_values.flat)

# Assign 1s using scipy csr_matrix for efficiency
data = np.ones(len(cols), dtype=int)
b = csr_matrix((data, (np.arange(len(row_indices)), cols)), 
               shape=(len(row_indices), len(num_cols))).toarray()

# Repeat 'A' and 'E' columns based on the sums of the numerical columns
repeated_A = np.repeat(df['A'].values, num_values.sum(axis=1))
repeated_E = np.repeat(df['E'].values, num_values.sum(axis=1))

# Create the final DataFrame
out = pd.DataFrame(b, columns=num_cols)
out['A'] = repeated_A
out['E'] = repeated_E

# Reset the index to ensure the output DataFrame has a continuous index
out = out.reset_index(drop=True)

print(out)
"""
  B  C  D  A  E
0  1  0  0  a  x
1  1  0  0  a  x
2  0  0  1  a  x
3  0  0  1  a  x
4  0  0  1  a  x
5  1  0  0  b  y
6  0  1  0  b  y
7  0  1  0  b  y
"""

If you want to use from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder then the Output will be a bit different.
# Define numerical columns
num_cols = ['B', 'C', 'D']

# Convert numerical columns to numpy array
num_values = df[num_cols].to_numpy()

# Build row indices to repeat
row_indices = np.repeat(np.arange(num_values.shape[0]), num_values.sum(axis=1))

# Build column indices to repeat
cols = np.repeat(np.tile(np.arange(num_values.shape[1]), num_values.shape[0]), num_values.flat)

# Assign 1s using scipy coo_matrix for efficiency
data = np.ones(len(cols), dtype=int)
b = coo_matrix((data, (np.arange(len(row_indices)), cols)), shape=(len(row_indices), len(num_cols))).toarray()

# Repeat and update DataFrame
out = df.iloc[row_indices].reset_index(drop=True)
out[num_cols] = b

# Use OneHotEncoder to encode the categorical column 'A'
encoder = OneHotEncoder(sparse_output=False, handle_unknown='ignore')
encoded_A = encoder.fit_transform(out[['A']])

# Convert encoded A to DataFrame
encoded_A_df = pd.DataFrame(encoded_A, columns=encoder.get_feature_names_out(['A']))
print(encoded_A_df)
"""
   A_a  A_b
0  1.0  0.0
1  1.0  0.0
2  1.0  0.0
3  1.0  0.0
4  1.0  0.0
5  0.0  1.0
6  0.0  1.0
7  0.0  1.0
"""
# Combine encoded A and the rest of the columns
result_df = pd.concat([encoded_A_df, out.drop(columns=['A'])], axis=1)

print(result_df)

   A_a  A_b  B  C  D  E
0  1.0  0.0  1  0  0  x
1  1.0  0.0  1  0  0  x
2  1.0  0.0  0  0  1  x
3  1.0  0.0  0  0  1  x
4  1.0  0.0  0  0  1  x
5  0.0  1.0  1  0  0  y
6  0.0  1.0  0  1  0  y
7  0.0  1.0  0  1  0  y

without csr :
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

data = {
    'A': ['a', 'b'],
    'B': [2, 1],
    'C': [0, 2],
    'D': [3, 0],
    'E': ['x', 'y']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
'''
   A  B  C  D  E
0  a  2  0  3  x
1  b  1  2  0  y
'''
counts = df.iloc[:,1:-1]
'''
   B  C  D
0  2  0  3
1  1  2  0
'''
labels = df.iloc[:,0].values
lastCol = df.iloc[:,-1].values

totalCounts = counts.sum(axis=1)
repeatedLabels = np.repeat(labels,totalCounts)
repeatedLastCol = np.repeat(lastCol,totalCounts)

encoder  = OneHotEncoder(sparse_output = False)

count_indices = np.arange(counts.shape[1]).reshape(-1,1)
'''
[[0]
 [1]
 [2]]
'''
oneHotEncoded = encoder.fit_transform(count_indices)
'''
[[1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1.]]
'''
rowIndices,colIndices = np.nonzero(counts.values)
#colIndices : [0 2 0 1]

repeats = counts.values[rowIndices,colIndices]
#[2 3 1 2]
expandedIndices = np.repeat(colIndices,repeats)
#[0 0 2 2 2 0 1 1]

oneHotExpanded = oneHotEncoded[expandedIndices]

oneHot_df = pd.DataFrame(oneHotExpanded,columns= counts.columns)

res_df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({'A':repeatedLabels,'E':repeatedLastCol}), oneHot_df],axis=1)
print(res_df)
'''
   A  E    B    C    D
0  a  x  1.0  0.0  0.0
1  a  x  1.0  0.0  0.0
2  a  x  0.0  0.0  1.0
3  a  x  0.0  0.0  1.0
4  a  x  0.0  0.0  1.0
5  b  y  1.0  0.0  0.0
6  b  y  0.0  1.0  0.0
7  b  y  0.0  1.0  0.0
'''

same with np.eye :
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'A': ['a', 'b'],
    'B': [2, 1],
    'C': [0, 2],
    'D': [3, 0],
    'E': ['x', 'y']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

counts = cols = df.iloc[:,1:-1]
firstcol = df.iloc[:,0]
lastcol = df.iloc[:,-1]

repeated_firstcol = np.repeat(firstcol.values,cols.sum(axis=1))
repeated_lastcol = np.repeat(lastcol.values,cols.sum(axis=1))

e = np.eye(len(cols.columns))
rowIdx,colIdx = np.nonzero(cols.values)
repeats = cols.values[np.nonzero(cols.values)]
print(repeats)#[2 3 1 2]

expanded_colIdx  = np.repeat(colIdx,repeats)
print(expanded_colIdx)#[0 0 2 2 2 0 1 1]

one_hot_expanded = e[expanded_colIdx]
print(one_hot_expanded)
'''
[[1. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 1.]
 [1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0.]]
'''
one_hot_df = pd.DataFrame(one_hot_expanded,columns = cols.columns)
res_df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({'A':repeated_firstcol ,'E':repeated_lastcol}),one_hot_df],axis=1)
print(res_df)
'''
   A  E    B    C    D
0  a  x  1.0  0.0  0.0
1  a  x  1.0  0.0  0.0
2  a  x  0.0  0.0  1.0
3  a  x  0.0  0.0  1.0
4  a  x  0.0  0.0  1.0
5  b  y  1.0  0.0  0.0
6  b  y  0.0  1.0  0.0
7  b  y  0.0  1.0  0.0
'''

another way with stack :
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'A': ['a', 'b'],
    'B': [2, 1],
    'C': [0, 2],
    'D': [3, 0],
    'E': ['x', 'y']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

counts = cols = df.iloc[:,1:-1]
firstcol = df.iloc[:,0]
lastcol = df.iloc[:,-1]

repeated_firstcol = np.repeat(firstcol.values,cols.sum(axis=1))
repeated_lastcol = np.repeat(lastcol.values,cols.sum(axis=1))

e = np.eye(len(cols.columns))
rowIdx,colIdx = np.nonzero(cols.values)
repeats = cols.values[np.nonzero(cols.values)]
print(repeats)#[2 3 1 2]

expanded_colIdx  = np.repeat(colIdx,repeats)
print(expanded_colIdx)#[0 0 2 2 2 0 1 1]

one_hot_expanded = e[expanded_colIdx]
print(one_hot_expanded)
'''
[[1. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 1.]
 [1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0.]]
'''
# Concatenate the repeated columns with the one-hot encoded matrix
res_array = np.column_stack((repeated_firstcol, repeated_lastcol, one_hot_expanded))
print(res_array)
'''
[['a' 'x' 1.0 0.0 0.0]
 ['a' 'x' 1.0 0.0 0.0]
 ['a' 'x' 0.0 0.0 1.0]
 ['a' 'x' 0.0 0.0 1.0]
 ['a' 'x' 0.0 0.0 1.0]
 ['b' 'y' 1.0 0.0 0.0]
 ['b' 'y' 0.0 1.0 0.0]
 ['b' 'y' 0.0 1.0 0.0]]
'''
# Create the final DataFrame
res_df = pd.DataFrame(res_array, columns=['A', 'E'] + cols.columns.tolist())
print(res_df)
'''
   A  E    B    C    D
0  a  x  1.0  0.0  0.0
1  a  x  1.0  0.0  0.0
2  a  x  0.0  0.0  1.0
3  a  x  0.0  0.0  1.0
4  a  x  0.0  0.0  1.0
5  b  y  1.0  0.0  0.0
6  b  y  0.0  1.0  0.0
7  b  y  0.0  1.0  0.0
'''


Could you provide timings/memory profile I'm curious how this fairs differently on huge datasets? I'm thinking perhaps then it is better to switch to polars?

I had tested on DataFrame size of 1 million .
Time taken (sparse): 2.4724695682525635 seconds
Time taken (vectorized): 3.7996532917022705
